# Find the rotation angles of a triangle in 3D, given the coordinates of its vertices

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, trigonometry

I try to rotate and translate an equilateral triangle in 3D until his vertices reach some coordinates.

The vertices coordinates **F,G,H** and **F',G',H'** are known :

[image]

I was able to find the new centroid `c'` coordinates like this :

```
c'.x = ( F'.x + G'.x + H'.x ) / 3
c'.y = ( F'.y + G'.y + H'.y ) / 3
c'.z = ( F'.z + G'.z + H'.z ) / 3
```

So no problem to translate the triangle. But I can't find a way to calculate the rotations needed to put F'G'H' triangle in the right position...

**I have to know by how much the triangle F'G'H' has to be rotated in degrees, around each axis (x,y,z), knowing that the rotations of the initial triangle are 0°.**

By rotation for each axis, I'm talking about this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define the rotations? There are different conventions.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the convention, but basically, I have to know by how much the triangle F'G'H' has to be rotated in degrees, on each axis (x,y,z), knowing that the rotations of the initial triangle are 0°. (I updated the question).

Comment: I'm afraid 3D rotation are not that simple, for example, notice that rotating 90° around the X-axis and then 90° around the Y-axis is not the same as rotating 90° around the Y-axis and then 90° around the X-axis. that's why, as @Beta said there are different conventions. I suggest you read up about [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Quaternions) and [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions).

Comment: I think Euler angles is what I want, but the convention doesn't really help me calculating the angles...

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Rordigues' Rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula) formula?

Comment: Read about [motion synthesis](http://synthetica.eng.uci.edu/~mccarthy/bernierothcd/papers/MotionSynthesis.pdf) in kinematics to solve this problem.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643692/calculating-rectangle-3d-coordinate-with-coordinate-its-shadow 
When I post full answer it sovle your problem!

Comment: did you acomplish?

Answer (score 4):

trick is to find the normal vectors of the triangles using cross product b4 and after rotations

```
v1 = (F.x - G.x, F.y - G.y, F.z - G.z)
v2 = (F.x - H.x, F.y - H.y, F.z - H.z)
n  = cross_prod(v1, v2) # see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product
n  = n / norm(n) # normalize to unit vector

v'1 = (F'.x - G'.x, F'.y - G'.y, F'.z - G'.z)
v'2 = (F'.x - H'.x, F'.y - H'.y, F'.z - H'.z)
n'  = cross_prod(v'1, v'2)
n'  = n' / norm(n')

rot = arc_cos(n.x * n'.x + n.y * n'.y + n.z * n'.z)
```

Comment: thanks, I already tried to calculate the normal, but I don't see how I can get triangle rotation for each axis (I updated the question with a diagram).

Comment: are the precise angles in degrees what you want? or do you just want an affine transform that will take you from old triangle to new triangle?

Comment: I need the precise angles.

Comment: just want to point out that rotations around the 3 axes you drew are not unique, in the sense that you can rotate x -> y -> z or x -> z -> y, and depending on the sequence you rotate in, the angles will be different.

Comment: I would still suggest the normal vector approach to characterize the rotation. Any orientation change is 1. a change in normal vectors and 2. a rotation around the normal vector. Think of the earth, to achieve any orientation, you first tilt the north-south pole line, then you turn it.

Comment: You're right, I think it's a good approach. Maybe I can use the normal axis to find the rotation, Thanks!