# Find 3D points of equilateral triangle based on its 2D projected coordinates

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, geometry, projection

Assuming a 3D model made by three equidistant points and origin(0,0,0) set at their center. Distance between these points is known. These 3D points are seem by a camera which projection matrix is known. I can access each point (x,y) position on the camera plane.  I am trying to retrieve these points' 3D coordinates and *partially* build a model matrix.

So far, when I multiply a 2D point by the projection matrix I can find their correspondent 3D positions, but I am not sure how to proceed or what exactly to look for in order to help me to establish a relationship between these 3 points to recover the 3D model (scale, rotation) of this object.

Already tried to calculate the normal in order to get orientation using similar approach to an answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983977/find-the-rotation-angles-of-a-triangle-in-3d-given-the-coordinates-of-its-verti) but not there yet.

I am aware three points might be too few information for a single solution, but since the object is equilateral, rotation on the axis point the camera is not relevant.

Comment: Is the projection a central projection or can it in theory be arbitrary?

Comment: I would say a central projection. I am using a Pin-hole camera model.

Answer (score 0):

You can first unproject each of the three 2D points into 3D space with different depths (using the inverse projection matrix). Then, you have for each 2D point a ray, on which the actual point may lie. Let's represent the ray with

```
x(t) = p + t * d,
```

where `t` is a scalar parameter, `p1` is one of the unprojected points, and `d` is the difference between the two unprojected points. Then, given the known distance of the 3D points `r`, you want to find their locations of the rays. I.e., you want to find the parameters of the three rays `t1`, `t2`, `t3` such that

```
(p1 + t1 * d1 - p2 - t2 * d2)^2 = r^2
(p2 + t2 * d2 - p3 - t3 * d3)^2 = r^2
(p3 + t3 * d3 - p1 - t1 * d1)^2 = r^2
```

Unfortunately, this is pretty hard to solve analytically. If I am not mistaken, you would need to solve a polynomial of degree 8, which does not have an analytic solution.

So, you are left with numerical solvers. I would start with something simple and try [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#k_variables,_k_functions). Start with a reasonable positive `t` vector.

Comment: Thanks for leading the way. I have to study a little more about it before replying back. Do you think [this material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq3c6QpcAGc) and actually [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_4eUoqgWdc&list=PL4B3F8D4A5CAD8DA3&index=37) could also contribute to understanding the math behind it?

Comment: Maybe. Honestly, it is a bit long to go through. But the first slides look promising.

Comment: Thank you! some of these slides even include some application of pose estimation  algorithm on matlab. But as I am not familiar with the concepts nor the math concepts of this operation I need to study a little more. So basically I am trying to convert some points 2D positions tracked from a camera, to estimate the pose of an object in 3D, and project this object on another projection matrix. Or is there any way I could just convert from one projection matrix to another? I know I could use homography to transform points from one plane to another (in 2D).

Comment: What do you mean by projecting onto another projection matrix? Your question mentions only a single camera pose and thus only a single projection matrix.

Comment: I am still looking for implementing a way to estimate pose as the title suggests. The material I included the link might help. I am still trying to implement something based on the algorithm presented on the video. 

Sorry about last message, it was misleading. For a second, I thought I could have another option to solve my final goal (extra topic) regardless of going through implementing pose estimation.